# Compile OpenGL Program (Missing GL/gl.h)

Tags: compiling, opengl

I am a complete Linux/Ubuntu noob, so I apologize for any dumb portions of this question or follow up ones.

I am trying to get a program that my software engineering class's group wrote onto my home computer. At school, we have Linux, and it will compile and run fine there. I downloaded VMWare, installed Ubuntu on a virtual machine, and now am trying to get my program to open.

When ever I try to run my make file however, I get an error that says

```
gcc -I../include -pthread -O1 -c rain.c
In file included from rain.c:19:0:
../include/GL/glfw.h:176:21: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [rain.o] Error 1
```

Would anyone happen to know why it can't find this file, when it can on my school computers? And what I'd need to do to download it or get it in the right spot?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I'd guess you don't have whatever dev package(s) provide gl.h. `apt-file` is the command line tool to use.

First, make sure it's up to date:

```
apt-file update
```

Now you can write a search to answer "what package provides the gl.h file?"

```
apt-file search "gl.h"
```

I don't have an ubuntu box just now to check, but I'd guess the result will be something like mesa-dev or opengl-dev.

Once you know what package provides "gl.h", (let's pretend the result from apt-file is "libmesa-dev"), install it:

```
apt-get install libmesa-dev
```

More info on the apt family of commands: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried what you suggested and updated the original post with the output of the search.

Comment: Decided to just play around with it and downloaded the mesa-common-dev package. Then I managed to navigate to the usr/include/GL folder and found that it was there. I moved just copied/pasted it into my project's folder and it seemed to work. But then my project was giving an error that it needed a "glu.h" folder, so I downloaded the libcgal-dev package, and did the same thing with the copy/paste. After putting that in the correct folder, and running the make command, the project compiles and will run. So thank you very much for the help. Now I just need to get the graphics to slow down. :)

Comment: Glad you got the build to work! Your copy/paste is the quick and dirty, but properly, your includes might be wrong. I don't know much c++, but had a similar problem compiling some package from source. Solution, iirc, was like changing `#include <gl.h>` to `#include<gl/gl.h>`.

Comment: The includes were like that. What it is that I was making was a GLFW program that had all the libraries and such in it from the tar file that I downloaded. I'm not sure why it didn't work, because it will on my school's computers.

Comment: Oh, man thank you so much for teaching me to fish instead of just giving me the name of the package!

Comment: apt-file is amazing!

Comment: Thanks for the info on apt-file. Regarding the required package for GL/gl.h, it is: `mesa-common-dev`   (at least for Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: how do i delete the downloaded cache files after using apt-file.. to save space on server

Comment: @dw1 that's a great question! if you don't see it already answered on askubuntu, you should [ask it yourself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for one day, teach a man to fish and you feed him for a life time. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for the `apt-file`. BTW, to get only relevant replies we can use command `apt-file search "/usr/include/GL/gl.h"`

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04: `sudo apt install libgl-dev`

Comment: @wesinat0r I have rejected your edits twice now. They're not appropriate for this answer. Please consider instead amending [Richard's fine answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/866868/8515), or writing your own.

Answer (score 58):

For `GL/gl.h` use:

```
sudo apt install mesa-common-dev
```

You may also find these helpful, for, say, `GL/glu.h`:

```
sudo apt install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev
```

Comment: You might also want to include `libglfw3-dev libgles2-mesa-dev`

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 20.04:

`GL.h` can be installed from the package `libgl-dev`.

`sudo apt install libgl-dev`

Answer (score 1):

You can also build glproto ([link](https://www.x.org/archive/individual/proto/)), libdrm ([link](https://dri.freedesktop.org/libdrm/)), and then mesa ([link](http://www.mesa3d.org/download.html)) from source. While many other packages may contain this header file, it's important to go to the source. This will reduce the memory footprint of your installations and ensure you have the latest and/or greatest version.