# "fatal error: GL/glfw.h: No such file or directory #include <GL/glfw.h>" - How to solve it?

Tags: opengl, g++

I'm trying to install GLFW to develop a OpenGL 3.0+ program and I've followed a few tutorials on how to install GLFW and I keep getting this error. I know I have installed it correctly with cmake, make and make install.

I'm running on a HD5700 series and have installed the ATi drivers and it seems to be working just fine. Maybe the file is in a place it shouldn't be?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306703/compile-opengl-program-missing-gl-gl-h) a nice solution:

Install apt-file and ask it to find in which package is that file:

```
apt-file search glfw.h
```

After that install the library via apt-get install...

Worked for mee :)